# NpgsqlParameter Array of smallints is receiving 0 instead of null value from postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, npgsql, c++

I got strange result with NpgsqlParameter in C++/CLI project.

```
NpgsqlParameter^ status = wCMD->Parameters->Add(gcnew NpgsqlParameter("param1", NpgsqlDbType::Array | NpgsqlDbType::Smallint));
status->Direction = System::Data::ParameterDirection::InputOutput;
status->Value = DBNull::Value;
status->Size = 20;

CALL MySchema.MyProcedure(:param1);
```

In MyProcedure, I assign a array of null and 0 to param1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MySchema.MyProcedure(
    INOUT param1 smallint[])
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
        BEGIN
            param1 := array[null, 0];
            raise notice 'param1: %', param1;
$BODY$;
```

Then I got the following strange result in C++/CLI project: NpgsqlValue with arrays of shorts is [0, 0]

Could somebody help me to explain why NpgsqlParameter received arrays of zeros instead of null and 0?

Maybe NULL in C++ is 0? Or array cannot receive NULL?

How could I receive correct returned result from postgres? Example: NpgsqlValue with arrays of shorts is [NULL, 0]

I am using npgsql 4.1.12, postgresql 14.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Roji who is Lead dev of Npgsql, the PostgreSQL provider, answered me like this:

> Right, older versions of Npgsql indeed read null array elements as the default value for the CLR type; that meant that for int you'd get 0. Npgsql 6.0 changed this problematic behavior.
>
> You're using ParameterDirection.InputOutput; this means that when reading the value, Npgsql doesn't know which CLR type you want (short?[] or short[]); it defaults to assuming short[], and then throws because it sees a null that cannot be represented in that.
>
> My recommendation would be to not use ParameterDirection.InputOutput; you can simply call your stored function/procedure, and read the results via the regular NpgsqlDataReader; see these docs to understand that better. If you do this, then you can simply call NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<short?[]> to tell Npgsql exactly which type you're looking for, and you'll get the null as expected.
>
> If you don't want to go down this route, then you can modify Npgsql's behavior when reading non-generically (e.g. with InputOutput); see the Array Nullability Mode connection string parameter. That's Never by default (the behavior described above, but you can set it to Always to make Npgsql always return a nullable array, or PerInstance for nullable/non-nullable arrays to be returned based on the actual array contents.

For detail, please refer here: [Github-npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/5049)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).